# Understanding of cache size in mybatis

Tags: java, caching, mybatis

look at following fragment of code:

```
<cache
      eviction="FIFO"
      flushInterval="60000"
      size="512"
      readOnly="true"
/>
```

What does it mean `size` here?
We can read:

> The size can be set to any positive integer, keep in mind the size of
>   the objects your caching and the available memory resources of your
>   environment. The default is 1024.

I don't understand this. In my mapper file I have only one select with returned:  `List<HashMap<String, Object>>`.
When I set `size=2` I can't see any difference in comparison to for example `size=300`. I mean that cache is working - I done many different queries to database via this cached mapper. Every query was fetched from cache (after the first database hit).

So what is proper understanding of `size` paramter ?

Comment: It is the number of references. 1024 means 1024 object references can be cached, irrespective of the size of each. So size = 2 means it will cache 2 references and size = 300 means it will cache 300 references.

Comment: Ok, what about my question ? Why I can't see a difference between size=2 and size=300 ?

Comment: How many select queries do you have in the mapper? And what is the query? Is it the same each time? or uses parameters so that the list is different?

Comment: I tried to do very many queries (abuot 50). yes, it is the same query - but each query is parametrized with different integer (exactly each ) @MohamedSanaulla

Comment: (My doubts started when I saw GC over memory limit - application was very long time tested before I switch on cache - then there was no out of memory)